# Hosts file not working with bindings in IIS

Tags: iis, networking, hostname, hosts-file

I have added a website to IIS with a binding hostname of richard-danvers.dev assigned to port 80

I have then added an entry to the hostfile with the public ip address of the server and the host name:

```
51.141.98.202 richard-danvers.dev
```

I have also tried

```
127.0.0.1 richard-danvers.dev
```

this results in `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

when I ping the hostname I can see any changes I have made in the hostfile (e.g. 127.0.0.1) but it still does not work when trying to navigate to the site in a browser.

and I have also tried with the actual DNS record I have pointed to the public IP (this returns a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` and ping resolves but does not get any successful pings)

none of these seem to allow my website to be accessed. When I enter a binding without a hostname I can hit the website under localhost fine so can't understand what I've done wrong/missed.

Comment: You have done enough at IIS/DNS level. About why `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` happens, you should check elsewhere, like if anything else takes over port 80, which is quite common if you installed tons of software.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if anything else is using that port

Comment: BTW, you might also run some diagnostics, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html to make sure you use the right URLs (HTTP/HTTPS).

Comment: I'll give that a go thanks

Comment: @LexLi doesn't seem like anything is hogging the port and I attempted to turn off the firewall with no luck. It may also be worth mentioning this is an Azure VM.

Comment: What's the diagnostics report then? You might edit your question to include that.

Comment: finally got it working, looks like I had a lot of things wrong. Becuase I am using a .dev domain I had to ensure the ssl certificate was set up.

Comment: Then you can post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am using a .dev domain the ssl certificate had to be set up and configured in the bindings to allow the hostname to be hit.